# Android how to get file name

Tags: android, kotlin

So basically I have this app where I open filechooser and I want to put file name into specific box.

But in result I get this string **document:39**

The file I want to use is pdf and it's called **TestBook** and that's what I want to display

**There is how I launch file chooser:**

```
fun showFileChooser(activity: Activity)
{
        val filesIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT, MediaStore.Downloads.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI)

        activity.startActivityForResult(filesIntent, PICK_PDF_REQUEST_CODE)
}
```

**then on button click**

```
R.id.iv_add_file ->{
          if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)  == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
          {
            showFileChooser(this@AddBookActivity)
          }
          else
          {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,arrayOf(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE),
                            Constants.READ_STORAGE_PERMISSION_CODE)
          }
}
```

**and last onActivityResult**

```
if (requestCode == Constants.PICK_PDF_REQUEST_CODE)
{
   if (data != null)
   {
      mSelectedFileUri = data.data!!

      val filename = File(mSelectedFileUri!!.path).name
      et_book_file.setText(filename)

   }
}
```

Et_book_file is an EditText and as I mentioned at the beginning it shows string **document:39**

I tried with other files like jpg but it just displayed string **image:40**

Is there any obvious solution for this? Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 7):

You cannot directly access file name from content Uris, you have to use `contentResolver` to get the file name. Use this function to get the file name from Uri

```
fun getFileNameFromUri(context: Context, uri: Uri): String? {
    val fileName: String?
    val cursor = context.contentResolver.query(uri, null, null, null, null)
    cursor?.moveToFirst()
    fileName = cursor?.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(OpenableColumns.DISPLAY_NAME))
    cursor?.close()
    return fileName
}
```

Now you can call `getFileNameFromUri` method to get the file name

```
mSelectedFileUri?.let { uri ->
    val filename = getFileNameFromUri(this, uri)
    et_book_file.setText(filename)
}
```